# Memory error when running medium sized merge function ipython notebook jupyter

Tags: pandas, out-of-memory, ipython

I'm trying to merge around 100 dataframes with a for loop and am getting a memory error. I'm using ipython jupyter notebook

Here is a sample of the data:

```
    timestamp   Namecoin_cap
0   2013-04-28  5969081
1   2013-04-29  7006114
2   2013-04-30  7049003
```

Each frame is around 1000 lines long

[Here's the error in detail, I've also include my merge function.](http://pastebin.com/QTcPQ1jY)

[My system is currently using up 64% of it memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE0lR.png)

I have searched for similar issues but it seems most are for very large arrays >1GB, my data is relatively small in comparison.

EDIT: Something is suspicious. I wrote a beta program before, this was to test with 4 dataframes, i just exported that through pickle and it is 500kb. Now when i try to export the 100 frames one I get a memory error. It does however export a file that is 2GB. So i suspect somewhere down the line my code has created some kind of loop, creating a very large file. NB the 100 frames are stored in a dictionary

EDIT2: I have exported the scrypt to .py

http://pastebin.com/GqaHr7xc

[This is a .xlsx that cointains asset names the script needs](https://www.mediafire.com/?tev25yznxk2b6cd)

The script fetches data regarding various assets, then cleans it up and saves each asset to a data frame in a dictionary

I'd be really appreciative if someone could have a look and see if there's anything immediately wrong. Other wise please advise on what tests I can run.

EDIT3: I'm finding it really hard to understand why this is happening, the code worked fine in the beta, all i have done now is add more assets.

EDIT4: I ran I size check on the object (dict of dfs) and it is 1,066,793 bytes

EDIT5: The problem is in the merge function for coin 37

```
for coin in coins[:37]:
    data2['merged'] = pd.merge(left=data2['merged'],right=data2[coin], left_on='timestamp', right_on='timestamp', how='left')
```

This is when the error occurs.  `for coin in coins[:36]:' doesn't produce an error however`for coin in coins[:37]:' produces the error, any ideas ?

EDIT6: the 36th element is 'Syscoin', i did coins.remove('Syscoin') however the memory problem still occurs. So it seems to be a problem with the 36th element in coins no matter what the coin is

EDIT7: goCards suggestions seemed to work however the next part of the code:

```
merged = data2['merged']
merged['Total_MC'] = merged.drop('timestamp',axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```

Produces a memory error. I'm stumped

Comment: have you tried converting the notebook to a py file and running with python?

Comment: I did think to do this but i thought i would ask here first. Since this is the first reply i'll I try it now

Comment: @goCards I want to save the dictionary of data frames, do you know the best was to do this with recovery in mind ?

Comment: how is each dataframe related to eachother? They have the same key? or is it just one big table divided horizontally?

Comment: wow, ok I take back what I said, i just exported the dict of dataframes and the pickle file is 2GB not only that but I got an memory error just trying to save it. So i don't know if it saved properly. 
Each frame represents timestamps and market caps for various assets, the name of which is the key in the dict.

Comment: I ran your code with pandas 0.17.1, and I didn't have any memory explosion. I used the first 10 currencies on the website. Then saved to a csv file. The resulting file was 136KB.

Comment: Yes i get a similar result, the problem is in the merge function of coin 37 
`for coin in coins[:37]:
    data2['merged'] = pd.merge(left=data2['merged'],right=data2[coin], left_on='timestamp', right_on='timestamp', how='left')`

This is when the error occurs.  `for coin in coins[:36]:' doesn't produce an error however `for coin in coins[:37]:' produces the error, any ideas ?

Comment: see my editted post below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regard to storage, I would recommend using a simple csv over pickle. Csv is a more generic format. It is human readable,and you can check your data quality easier especially as your data grows.

```
file_template_string='%s.csv'
for eachKey in dfDict:
    filename = file_template_string%(eachKey)
    dfDict[eachKey].to_csv(filename)
```

If you need to date the files you can also put a timestamp in the filename.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
cur = time.time()
cur = datetime.fromtimestamp(cur)
file_template_string = "%s_{0}.csv".format(cur.strftime("%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S"))
```

There are some obvious errors in your code.

```
for coin in coins: #line 61,89
for coin in data: #should be

df = data2['Namecoin'] #line 87
keys = data2.keys()
keys.remove('Namecoin')
for coin in keys:
    df = pd.merge(left=df,right=data2[coin], left_on='timestamp', right_on='timestamp', how='left')
```

Comment: Thank you, i will keep this in mind. It seems like there is some bug in my code that is creating a file magnitudes larger than it should be

Comment: Hm interesting, so I made the alterations and still get the memory error. Could you paste your entire code so I can compare ?

Comment: It seems the problems goes deeper than expected. I have made another post I you would like to view it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35255712/function-should-clean-data-to-half-the-size-instead-it-enlarges-it-by-an-order

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happened to me! 
"MemoryError:" by notebook on execution of pandas. I have also screen printed quite lot of observations before issued happened.

Reinstalling Anaconda didn't help. Later realized that i was working with IPython notebook instead Jupyter notebook. Switched to Jupyter notebook. Everything worked fine!