# Function should clean data to half the size, instead it enlarges it by an order of magnitude

Tags: python, memory, pandas, dataframe

This has been driving me nuts all week weekend. I am trying merge data for different assets around a common timestamp. Each asset's data is a value in dictionary. The data of interest is stored in lists in one column, so this needs to be separated first. Here is a sample of the unprocessed df:

```
data['Dogecoin'].head()

    market_cap_by_available_supply  price_btc   price_usd   volume_usd
0   [1387118554000, 3488670]    [1387118554000, 6.58771e-07]    [1387118554000, 0.000558776]    [1387118554000, 0.0]
1   [1387243928000, 1619159]    [1387243928000, 3.18752e-07]    [1387243928000, 0.000218176]    [1387243928000, 0.0]
2   [1387336027000, 2191987]    [1387336027000, 4.10802e-07]    [1387336027000, 0.000267749]    [1387336027000, 0.0]
```

Then I apply this function to separate market_cap_by_available_supply, saving it's components into a new dataframe for that asset:

```
data2 = {}
#sorting function 
for coin in data:
    #seperates timestamp and marketcap from their respective list inside each element
    TS = data[coin].market_cap_by_available_supply.map(lambda r: r[0])
    cap = data[coin].market_cap_by_available_supply.map(lambda r: r[1])
    #Creates DataFrame and stores timestamp and marketcap data into dictionairy
    df = DataFrame(columns=['timestamp','cap'])
    df.timestamp = TS
    df.cap = cap
    df.columns = ['timestamp',str(coin)+'_cap']
    data2[coin] = df
    #converts timestamp into datetime 'yyy-mm-dd'
    data2[coin]['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data2[coin]['timestamp'], unit='ms').dt.date
```

It seemed to work perfectly, producing the correct data, sample:

```
data2['Namecoin'].head()
timestamp   Namecoin_cap
0   2013-04-28  5969081
1   2013-04-29  7006114
2   2013-04-30  7049003
3   2013-05-01  6366350
4   2013-05-02  5848626
```

However when I attempted to merge all dataframes, I got a memory error, I've spent hours trying to figure out the root and it seems like the 'sorting function' above is increasing the size of the dataframe from 12Mb to 131Mb! It should do this opposite. Any ideas ?

On a side note here is the data 
https://www.mediafire.com/?9pcwroe1x35nnwl

I open it with this pickle funtion

```
with open("CMC_no_tuple_data.pickle", "rb") as myFile:
    data = pickle.load(myFile)
```

EDIT: Sorry for the typo in the pickle file name. 
@Goyo to compute the size i simple saved data and data 2 via pickle.dump and looked at their respective sizes 
@ Padraic Cunningham you used the sort funtion i provided and it produced a smaller file ?? This is not my case and i get a memory error when trying to merge the dataframes

Comment: How are you merging?

Comment: "it seems like the 'sorting function' above is increasing the size of the dataframe from 12Mb to 131Mb" What sorting function are you talking about? If you mean the for loop you wrote, the dataframes in data2 are smaller than those in data so you are actually decreasing the size if each dataframe.

Comment: That's exactly what the problem is. The data frames are smaller however the size of the dictionary (of dataframes) that is produces is 13x the size

Comment: Do you mean the size of `data` vs the size of `data2`? How do you compute that size?

Comment: trying import : 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 1024: ordinal not in range(128)'  .  the name of the file is ""CMC_no_tuple_data.pickle" instead of "CMC_tuple_data.pickle". is it the problem ?

Comment: data2  has way less data for mw

Comment: @BM I do not think so. The file name must be a typo that you can fix to run the code. It is python2 code, in order to make it work in python3 you may need to play with the encoding, mode...

Comment: I have made an edit in my post

Comment: @DavidHancock `pickle.dump(data2, f)` gives me a 7.0 MB file while `pickle.dump(data, f)` is 12.2 MB (the same size as "CMC_no_tuple_data.pickle").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you merge your dataframes, you are doing a join on values that are not unique. When you are joining all these dataframes together, you are getting many matches. As you add more and more currencies you are getting something similar to a Cartesian product rather than a join. In the snippet below, I added code to sort the values and then remove duplicates.

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd

coins='''
Bitcoin
Ripple
Ethereum
Litecoin
Dogecoin
Dash
Peercoin
MaidSafeCoin
Stellar
Factom
Nxt
BitShares
'''
coins = coins.split('\n')
API = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/datapoints/'
data = {}

for coin in coins:
    print(coin)
    try:
        data[coin]=(pd.read_json(API + coin))
    except: pass
data2 = {}
for coin in data:
    TS = data[coin].market_cap_by_available_supply.map(lambda r: r[0])
    TS = pd.to_datetime(TS,unit='ms').dt.date
    cap = data[coin].market_cap_by_available_supply.map(lambda r: r[1])
    df = DataFrame(columns=['timestamp','cap'])
    df.timestamp = TS
    df.cap = cap
    df.columns = ['timestamp',coin+'_cap']
    df.sort_values(by=['timestamp',coin+'_cap'])
    df= df.drop_duplicates(subset='timestamp',keep='last')
    data2[coin] = df

df = data2['Bitcoin']
keys = data2.keys()
keys.remove('Bitcoin')
for coin in keys:
    df = pd.merge(left=df,right=data2[coin],left_on='timestamp', right_on='timestamp', how='left')
    print len(df),len(df.columns)
df.to_csv('caps.csv')
```

EDIT:I have added a table belowing showing how the size of the table grows as you do your join operation.

This table shows the number of rows after joining 5,10,15,20,25, and 30 currencies.

```
Rows,Columns
1015 5
1255 10
5095 15
132071 20
4195303 25
16778215 30
```

This table shows how removing duplicates makes your joins only match a single row.

```
Rows,Columns
1000 5
1000 10
1000 15
1000 20
1000 25
1000 30
```

Comment: @DavidHancock Note that I sorted the values and took the max.

Comment: you would be discarding just one row in one dataframe (namely Pebblecoin, 2016-02-06). Besides, `drop_duplicates` does not need sorting (you are not using the sorted values anyway).

Comment: @Goyo If you look at the data set from the original question, there are many duplicate timestamps for each currency. I am removing duplicates for all the currencies, and then you can do a join.

Comment: Not really sure what you are doing here. After running your code al caps become nan. And I do not have 'Bitcoin' in the keys.

Comment: @Goyo I included the entire code in the post above. The nan values were a typo in the column names. I have corrected that as well.

Comment: Yes, using `subset='timestamp'` you actually remove a lot of rows and you can join on the timestamps. They are not duplicated rows though, just duplicated timestamps. You are throwing away data which is not duplicated. I guess it is acceptable in this case.

Comment: @Goyo I agree that they are not duplicate data, but they will still join with all the rows with the same time stamp. If it is necessary to keep the rows, then th time resolution  needs to change from daily to hourly.